# how to get locale dynamically from dayjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs?

Tags: npm, locale, dayjs

When I use like `dayjs(date).locale('te').format('YYYY MMM DD')`, then I get Month value in english. For working with locale, I have to import locale.

```
import * as locale from 'dayjs/locale/te';
```

The problem is that I don't see a way to dynamically import a locale. I don't have access to nodejs require() function. I have react based application. How to mitigate this issue?

Comment: if you need to use require in browser you need to use browserify

Comment: so what is your expected output, What are you trying to achieve can you explain more

Comment: I need month translated to the locale language. For which i need conditional loading of a locale.

Answer (score 7):

A workaround for dynamic Imports without errors:

```js
const locales = {
  de: () => import('dayjs/locale/de'),
  en: () => import('dayjs/locale/en'),
}

function loadLocale (language) {
  locales[language]().then(() => dayjs.locale(language))
}
```

Comment: goog solution, since I don't want to copy all of the locales chunks into my build folder

Comment: Hello, I like your answer. I have an issue about locales not being a function. Also I use typescript. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use import as import expression and dynamically import whatever you want.
for example:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import localeData from "dayjs/plugin/localeData";
dayjs.extend(localeData);

const LOCALE = "de";

import(`dayjs/locale/${LOCALE}`)
.then(() => {
  dayjs.locale(LOCALE);
  console.log(dayjs.weekdays());
});
```

You can see a working example [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dayjs-dynamic-locale0import-s64gx?file=/src/index.js).

for more information on dynamic imports I suggest you to read https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Comment: Neat solution! But it might be better to add `.js` into the import statement as it might provoke compile errors if used in webpack without typescript configuration: 
import(`dayjs/locale/${LOCALE}.js`)

Comment: @Hexodus for me the `.js` was the crucial bit for my typescript app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first import needed locale files as below

```
import 'dayjs/locale/te'
import 'dayjs/locale/en'
```

Then you can switch between locals dynamically as below operations

```
dayjs().locale('en').format()
dayjs('2018-4-28', { locale: 'te' })
```

Comment: But that will pull un-necessary code. I have to do import conditionally.

Comment: It seems no way for conditional import.

Comment: This answer is non relevant, it does not address the question regarding dynamic importing.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do if you don't mind adding a promise there is to dynamically import the locale you need. The code would look like this:

```
const convertToLocale = (date, locale) => {
  return import(`dayjs/locale/${locale}`)
    .then(() => dayjs(date).locale(locale));
}
```

This will load all locale files as the import you mentioned would without the need to add the import statements by hand.

Comment: @ Efstathios Oikonomou it is not working. Dynamic import it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
const language = {
    en: import('dayjs/locale/en'),
    te: import('dayjs/locale/te')
}

language['te'].then(lng => { console.log((dayjs(new Date()).locale(lng.name).format('YYYY MMMM DD')))})
```