# dayjs with react-native - how to load all dayjs locales?

Tags: react-native, dayjs

Tried to import dynamically locale following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658142/1846993).

```
import(`dayjs/locale/${currentLocale}`)
    .then(() => {
        dayjs.locale(currentLocale);
    });
```

Got the error:

> Invalid call at line 26: import("dayjs/locale/" + currentLocale)

I guess it more the "web way" - Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60700930/1846993) I understand that I need to load all dayjs locales in compile time.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can can do something like

```
const locale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale()
dayjs.locale(locale)
```

and you'll need to import the needed locales in order for them to be included in the bundle

```
import 'dayjs/locale/te'
import 'dayjs/locale/en'
...etc
```

this requires using react-native-device-info, you can try to find other ways of getting the locale tho and then set the locale

Comment: Thanks! the thing is that by default dayjs comes with only 'en' locale - I want to load all dayjs locales prior to choosing the specific one I need

Comment: oh then I think you'd have to import all of the needed locales so that they get included in the js bundle

Comment: thanks - the question is how should I do that?

Comment: oh, that's just a matter of adding this inside your app
```
import 'dayjs/locale/te'
import 'dayjs/locale/en'
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks! isnt there a syntax something like:
import * as days from dayjs/locale/*

Comment: I'm not sure depends on how the locales are being exported, i came across this discussion, you might be interested in the last couple of comments https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1041